# How can I disable the UITableView selection?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

When you tap a row in a `UITableView`, the row is highlighted and selected. Is it possible to disable this so tapping a row does nothing?

Comment: The original question has a bad title. OP want's primarily to disable `selection`, and of course `highlighting` gets disabled with that. Many high voted answers explain how to `disable selection`and does not address disabling `highlighting`. To disable only highlighting use `cell.selectionStyle = .None` or go to `storyboard / cell / Selection = None`

Comment: Please update either the title or the post. I'm confused. And based on this question, I have no idea what provided answers are meant to do.

Answer (score 2029, accepted):

All you have to do is set the selection style on the `UITableViewCell` instance using either:

Objective-C:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

or

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Swift 2:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

Swift 3 and 4.x:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Further, make sure you either don't implement `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view delegate or explicitly exclude the cells you want to have no action if you do implement it.

[More info here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100825164330/http://developer.apple.com:80/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/selectionStyle) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100901120334/http://developer.apple.com:80/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)

Comment: @Tony That does work very well, thanks! How about posting it as an answer so we can upvote it to the top?

Comment: @Tony It's bad idea if you have a UITextField inside the cell.

Comment: @TonyMillion it's also a bad idea if you want to use in-built editing controls, such as swipe-to-delete.  If you set userInteractionEnabled to NO then the delete button does not respond to user touch events.

Comment: late to this thread, but instead of userInteraction, use cell.allowsSelection. That stops the cell's interaction methods but doesn't block the regular UIView responder stuff.

Comment: in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884691/what-are-the-possible-reasons-why-voidtableviewuitableview-tableview-dids/12886017#12886017 setting the cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO actually makes the didSelectRowAtIndexPath easier to trigger.

Comment: Setting cell.userInteractionEnable=No will not stop triggering a didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Indeed, I cannot select the cell (didSelectRowAtIndexPath not triggered) after setting userInteractionEnable = NO.

Comment: @TonyMillion Be aware that if you use `userInteractionEnabled` on a `UITableViewCell`, the textLabel's color will change to grey, and you CAN NOT prevent that.

Comment: In XCode, you could select the table view, and in the attributes inspector set "Selection" to "No Selection"

Comment: I will up vote the answer, but just to be clear, the OP asked only for disabling "highlighting", no to disable entire cell interaction, so all this comments are offtopic.

Comment: Just to add a thing. In swift the one suggested become: cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

Comment: @TonyMillion it's also a bad idea if you want enable copying of a UILabel's text inside the cell.

Comment: iOS 9: seems `cell.allowsSelection` is no longer available. Also note that disabling `userInteraction` makes it impossible to change `cell.textLabel.textColor`

Comment: Put this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. In `init`, it didn't work.

Comment: `cell.selectionStyle = .None`  Its enough for me.

Comment: **swift4.2**   in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {` cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none

Comment: Hmm something fishy is going on here

Answer (score 652):

For me, the following worked fine:

```
tableView.allowsSelection = false
```

This means `didSelectRowAt#` simply won't work. That is to say, touching a row of the table, as such, will do absolutely nothing. (And hence, obviously, there will never be a selected-animation.)

(Note that if, on the cells, you have `UIButton` or any other controls, of course those controls will still work. Any controls you happen to have on the table cell, are totally unrelated to UITableView's ability to allow you to "select a row" using `didSelectRowAt#`.)

Another point to note is that: This doesn't work when the `UITableView` is in editing mode. To restrict cell selection in editing mode use the code as below:

```
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = false
```

Comment: this finally worked for me, I tried to use 
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; 
but it didn't work.

One thing to note: it should be:
 tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
not false.

Comment: I think, this is best option. Buttons on cells are active with this, but text are not active.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer and has this many up votes? It does not answer the question at all! You need to set the `selectionStyle` property on the cell: `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None` in Swift, or `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` in Objective-C.

Comment: Worked well for me, I can still interact with textfields, picker etc in my cells

Comment: Yes, this answer is the correct one for the given question. OPs wants to disable selection for the cell.

Comment: This works for me in swift 2. `tableView.allowSelection = false `

Comment: There's a few ways to do this depending on what is desired. No selection style and no selection can both work, or can both fail. Here's an example. If you want to select the cell and have the `tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath` to be called, `cell.selectionStyle = .None` is desired. If you don't want or care for that delegate function to be called (ie having a textfield in a tableViewCell) setting `tableView.allowsSelection = false` is just fine.

Comment: it is Google's fault for navigating users when searching 'how to disable uitableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath background color'. So blame it on Google

Comment: 100% wrong answer. This won't disable highlighting, this will disable selection completely

Comment: Bad solution for me - disables selection. Com'on guys.

Comment: @nodebase how come others say this *does* work? I'm confused

Comment: This ended up working for me `tableView.allowsSelection = false` in the viewWillAppear method.

Comment: **swift4.2**   in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {` cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none

Comment: If you're using the `cell.selectionStyle = .none` method and UI elements in your cell still aren't responding to taps, make sure you've added them as subviews of the UITableViewCell's contentView: `contentView.addSubview(button)`

Answer (score 366):

Because I've read this post recently and it has helped me, I wanted to post another answer to consolidate all of the answers (for posterity).

---

So, there are actually 5 different answers depending on your desired logic and/or result:

1.To disable the blue highlighting without changing any other interaction of the cell:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

I use this when I have a UIButton - or some other control(s) - hosted in a UITableViewCell and I want the user to be able to interact with the controls but not the cell itself.

<sub>***NOTE***: As Tony Million noted above, this does NOT prevent `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. I get around this by simple "if" statements, most often testing for the section and avoiding action for a particular section.</sub>

Another way I thought of to test for the tapping of a cell like this is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // A case was selected, so push into the CaseDetailViewController
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.selectionStyle != UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone) {
        // Handle tap code here
    }
}
```

2.To do this for an entire table, you can apply the above solution to each cell in the table, but you can also do this:

```
[tableView setAllowsSelection:NO];
```

<sub>**In my testing, this still allows controls inside the `UITableViewCell` to be interactive.**</sub>

3.To make a cell "read-only", you can simply do this:

```
[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

4.To make an entire table "read-only"

```
[tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

5.To determine on-the-fly whether to highlight a cell (which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13167946/394484) implicitly includes selection), you can implement the following `UITableViewDelegate` protocol method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: If you load the cell design from a nib, the checkbox (in IB) will work just fine for #3 (and on tables for #4). For #4 vs #2, is the difference whether or not controls inside the cell will be interactive?

Comment: Yes. If you want to disable selection but allow UIButtons, etc... to continue to support user interaction, use #2. If you want a completely read-only cell, use #4. Of course, why you would have anything but UIViews or UILabels in a non-interactive cell is beyond me. Maybe somebody would want to disable all interaction while something else is occurring.

Comment: @mbm30075 #1 the first one seems to best answer of all the 4 options

Comment: This is the most complete answer!

Comment: @andyPaul It depends on what you're trying to achieve. I often use #1 when I want to preserve user interaction, but that's not always that case. Thanks!

Comment: #4 is a terrible idea, doing this will also disable scrolling in the table view

Comment: @simon Actually, it's not a terrible idea; it's one option that may or may not be a good option depending on your circumstances. Also, #4 disables USER scrolling; you could still implement your own, if necessary. I agree #4 isn't useful MUCH, but it isn't a terrible idea.

Comment: Very good and complete answer! Saved me a lot of issues I had with a Button and TextField inside my cell

Comment: For completeness could you please add a shout-out for [`tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13167946/2547229), which is _generally_ (not always) my preferred approach.

Answer (score 91):

To sum up what I believe are the correct answers based on my own experience in implementing this:

If you want to disable selection for just some of the cells, use:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

As well as preventing selection, this also stops tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: being called for the cells that have it set. (Credit goes to Tony Million for this answer, thanks!)

If you have buttons in your cells that need to be clicked, you need to instead:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

and you also need to ignore any clicks on the cell in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

If you want to disable selection for the whole table, use:

```
tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
```

(Credit to Paulo De Barros, thanks!)

Comment: what If we have a button in our cell ?

Comment: `tableView.allowsSelection = NO;` doesn't allow buttons clicks inside cells... has something changed since? I know this post is old

Comment: @WestonAMitchell You may want to check out the sentence beginning "If you have buttons in your cells that need to be clicked". You need to use the setSelectionStyle solution.

Comment: @JosephH I had that set already. I actually found out that my issue was with my constraints using `self` of UITableViewCell to set constraints of its buttons, whilst I should have been using self.contentView. Also making sure that all views are vertically constrained from top of contentView, to bottom.

Answer (score 60):

As of iOS 6.0, `UITableViewDelegate` has `tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:`. (Read about it in the iOS [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:).)

This method lets you mark specific rows as unhighlightable (and implicitly, unselectable) without having to change a cell's selection style, messing with the cell's event handling with `userInteractionEnabled = NO`, or any other techniques documented here.

Comment: Stumbled across this thread and I was shocked to see so many other answers prior to this one. This is without a doubt the proper way.

Comment: This is indeed the correct and only answer that should be considered. Anything else mentioning userInteraction is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 52):

You can also disable selection of row from interface builder itself by choosing `NoSelection` from the `selection` option(of UITableView Properties) in inspector pane as shown in the below image

[image: UITableView Inspector]

Comment: Best solution IMHO

Comment: I often use this solution

Answer (score 49):

**FIXED SOLUTION FOR SWIFT 3**

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 41):

EDIT: for newer Swift it is changed to:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

See this for more info:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/selectionstyle

In case anyone needs answer for [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/):

```
cell.selectionStyle = .None
```

Comment: we can also use this

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

Answer (score 38):

In your `UITableViewCell`'s **XIB** in Attribute Inspector set value of `Selection` to `None`.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I still wanted the didSelect... notification but without the visible indication of selection.  Thanks!

Answer (score 36):

If you want selection to only flash, not remain in the selected state, you can call, in

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

the following

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

so it will flash the selected state and revert.

Comment: With this approach, the row instantly highlights and then fades out over a half-second. This is how Apple styles their Settings menus, so it looks good to me.

Answer (score 31):

From the `UITableViewDelegate` Protocol you can use the method `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` 
and `return nil` if you don't want the row selected.

In the same way the you can use the `willDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method and `return nil` if you don't want the row to deselect.

Comment: I don't like this method because it still shows the cell in its highlighted state until touch up.

Comment: that's exactly why I like it :-)

Answer (score 31):

This is what I use ,in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` write this code.:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 29):

1- All you have to do is set the **selection style on the `UITableViewCell`** instance using either:

**Objective-C:**

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

or

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

**Swift 2:**

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

**Swift 3:**

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

2 - Don't implement -**`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`** in your table view `delegate` or explicitly exclude the cells you want to have no action if you do implement it.

3 - Further,You can also do it from the storyboard. Click the table view cell and in the attributes inspector under Table View Cell, change the drop down next to Selection to None.

4 - You can disable table cell highlight using below code in (iOS) **Xcode 9 , Swift 4.0**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OpenTbCell") as! OpenTbCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell


}
```

Answer (score 21):

### Objective-C:

1. Below snippet disable highlighting but it also disable the call to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. So if you are not implementing `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` then use below method. This should be added when you are creating the table. This will work on buttons and `UITextField` inside the cell though.

   ```
   self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
   ```
2. Below snippet disable highlighting and it doesn't disable the call to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Set the selection style of cell to None in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

   ```
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   ```
3. Below snippet disable everything on the cell. This will disable the interaction to `buttons`, `textfields`:

   ```
   self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false;
   ```

### Swift:

Below are the `Swift` equivalent of above `Objective-C` solutions:

1. Replacement of First Solution

   ```
   self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
   ```
2. Replacement of Second Solution

   ```
   cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
   ```
3. Replacement of Third Solution

   ```
   self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false
   ```

Answer (score 20):

Try to type:

```
cell.selected = NO;
```

It will deselect your row when needed.

In Swift3 ...

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let r = indexPath.row
    print("clicked .. \(r)")
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.setSelected(false, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 3,4 and 5**

**Better practice**, write code in `UITableViewCell`

For example, you have `UITableViewCell` with the name `MyCell`,
In `awakeFromNib` just write `self.selectionStyle = .none`

Full example:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I've been battling with this quite profusely too, having a control in my `UITableViewCell` prohibited the use of `userInteractionEnabled` property. I have a 3 cell static table for settings, 2 with dates, 1 with an on/off switch. After playing about in Storyboard/IB i've managed to make the bottom one non-selectable, but when you tap it the selection from one of the top rows disappears. Here is a WIP image of my settings UITableView:

[image: Settings UITableView]

If you tap the 3rd row nothing at all happens, the selection will stay on the second row. The functionality is practically a copy of Apple's Calendar app's add event time selection screen.

The code is surprisingly compatible, all the way down to IOS2 =/:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        return nil;
    }
    return indexPath;
}
```

This works in conjunction with setting the selection style to none, so the cell doesn't flicker on touch down events

Answer (score 11):

We can write code like

```
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

but when we have **custom cell xib** above line **give warning** at that time for

**custom cell xib**

we need to **set selection style None from the interface builder**

Answer (score 11):

You just have to put this code into cellForRowAtIndexPath

To disable the cell's selection property:(While tapping the cell).

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

Comment: Thank you, I have an image in my cell and a label above it. I've set the label background, but everytime I'd click the background would disappear, this has solved it.

Answer (score 11):

From **UITableViewDataSource** Protocol, inside method `cellForRowAt` add:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER", for: indexPath)                
cell.selectionStyle = .none
return cell
```

OR

You can goto Storyboard > Select Cell > Identity Inspector > Selection and select none from dropdown.

Answer (score 10):

I am using this, which works for me.

```
cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

and

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

and you can also set selection style using interfacebuilder.

Answer (score 8):

Directly disable highlighting of TableViewCell into storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 7):

While this is the best and easiest solution to prevent a row from showing the highlight during selection

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

I'd like to also suggest that it's occasionally useful to briefly show that the row has been selected and then turning it off. This alerts the users with a confirmation of what they intended to select:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Disable selection for all UITableViewCells in the UITableView**

```
tableView.allowsSelection = false
```

**Disable selection for specific UITableViewCells**

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
```

Answer (score 6):

To disable the highlighting of the UItableviewcell

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

And should not allow the user to interact with the cell.

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 6):

You Can also set the background color to Clear to achieve the same effect as `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`, in case you don't want to/ can't use `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

You would use code like the following:

```
UIView *backgroundColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
backgroundColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView: backgroundColorView];
```

This may ***degrade*** your performance as your adding an *extra* colored view to **each** cell.

Answer (score 6):

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 6):

**You can use :**

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

in the cell for row at index path method of your UITableView.

**Also you can use :**

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

in the tableview didselectrowatindexpath method.

Comment: It's now `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none` in Swift 3.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it from the storyboard. Click the table view cell and in the attributes inspector under Table View Cell, change the drop down next to Selection to None.

Answer (score 6):

I've gone through all answers and what worked for my use case was the following:

```swift
tableView.allowSelection = false
```

```swift
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    true
}
```

This way the table remains focusable, the user can scroll through its elements but is unable to "press / select" them.

Simply setting `cell.selectionStyle = .none` will allow the list element to be selectable (just not leave a gray selection mark behind). And just setting `allowSelection = false` would cause my table not to be focusable. Users wouldn't be able to scroll through the elements.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 5):

The best solution would be **Making The selection Style None**

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

However, Here we are considering the fact that there are no custom images used for selected state.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ....

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setSelected:NO animated:NO];
[cell setHighlighted:NO animated:NO];
```

Happy coding !!!

Answer (score 5):

**Swift Solution w/ Custom Cell:**

```
import Foundation

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
  {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
  {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use *selectionStyle* property of UITableViewCell

```
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Or

```
 [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Also, do not implement below delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { ... }
```

If you have created Xib/Storyboard file then you can change *setUserInteractionEnabled* 
property of tableview to *No* by unchecking it.
This will make your tableview to Read-Only.

Answer (score 4):

The better approach will be:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

This approach will not call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 3):

**You can disable table cell highight  using below code in (iOS) Xcode 9 , Swift 4.0**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OpenTbCell") as! OpenTbCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell


}
```

Answer (score 2):

At least as of iOS 6, you can override methods in your custom cell to prevent the blue highlight.  No other interaction is disabled or affected.  All three must be overridden.

```
- (void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
}

- (void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
}

- (void) setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***Scenario - 1***

If you don't want selection for some specific cells on the **tableview**, you can set selection style in **cellForRow** function for those cells.

**Objective-C**

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

***Scenario - 2***

For disabling selection on the whole table view :

**Objective-C**

```
self.tableView.allowsSelection = false;
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple stuff. Before returning the tableview Cell use the style property of the table view cell.

Just write this line of code before returning table view cell
`cell.selectionStyle = .none`