# iOS: tableviewcell question

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable the UITableView selection highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting)

I am programatically making the way my cell look.

When I click on the cell however, the table is highlighted. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [selectionStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/selectionStyle) property:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```