# How to make cells in UITableView not turn blue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a UITableView and the cells I am using in this view should do nothing when I click them. I can't turn off UserInteraction though because then I am not able to click on the accessory (detailDisclosureButton). So how can I make them stop turning blue and still allow them to click on the accessory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable the UITableView selection highlighting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting)

Comment: On the plus side, that question has the answer you need `:)`

Comment: Also, don't forget that that answer below doesn't prevent `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` from firing. Just because you won't SEE the selection doesn't mean it won't HAPPEN. I say this just to remind you to handle for that in the method I mentioned above.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, the `selectionStyle` property of cell is `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue`. Change it to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

Comment: Thank you very much pratikshabhisikar. I appreciate your quick and correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

When you're generating the UITableViewCell (within the UITableView's `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method call), simply set the `selectionStyle` property to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

Set the [UITableViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

Use the UITabelViewCell `selectionStyle` property.

```
myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
```

Comment: I like your answer and your user name.

Comment: The OP specifically said that he needs to allow selection so the cell accessory can be tapped.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding the selection style to none or gray. By default it is blue.

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

You need to write this code in the method "- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath".

Answer (score 2):

If you want use to select cell add below code in method viewDidLoad

> self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

moreover you can disable selection overall for your whole table by adding:

> self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;

Answer (score 1):

It can easily done by **StoryBoard** without writing one line of code.
In your `UITableViewCell's` **XIB** in **Attribute Inspector** set value of Selection to **Gray** or **None** to stop a cell turning blue on selection and it still be selectable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Programtically**
Default UITableViewCell is UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue
Change it UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone.

myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

**By using StoryBoard**

[image]