# How do I remove UITableViewCell action on finger tap?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've just created UITableViewCell. I added to it two buttons. Then I set transparent background to the cell.

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```

But there is a problem. When user tapped on cell it changed the color to blue. But I don't want to see any reaction when a user is tapping.

Please see screenshots.

[image]

tapped action

[image]

Comment: Duplicate entry [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting

Comment: This might be a duplicate entry [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update for Swift 5:**

set the selection style to `none`

```swift
    cell.selectionStyle = .none;
```

Don't use  - `cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`
Or your buttons won't work.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways:

1.`cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` (to make cell 'ready-only' - this includes the buttons)

2.`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` (to disable just highlighting)

3.`tableView.allowsSelection = NO;` (disables just highlighting for whole table)

4.`tableView.UserInteractionEnabled:NO;` (to make whole table 'ready-only' - including buttons)

Comment: If he will set the cell.userInteractionEnabled to no the buttons will not work. same with tableView.allowselection

Comment: I've added description to all now.

Answer (score 0):

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** solution:

```
// disable selection for a specific cell
cell.selectionStyle = .none

// disable selection for all cells inside your TableView
tableView.allowsSelection = false
```