# Table view cells do not lose highlight on touch up

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When I click a cell it selects, but it stays blue on touch up. I want the blue highlight to leave on touch up (but it's important that it highlights in the first place).

This last answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting) mentions something about `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, but I can't figure out how to use that to do what I want. Also, I do need `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to still be called, I just want the cell to unhighlight on touch-up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following where appropriate:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

e.g. in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

This will deselect the row at the specified index path.

You could also be interested in `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` property in `UITableViewController`. If this property is set to yes then the controller clears the selection when the table appears. In default it set to YES.

[Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewController/clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear).