# What are the possible reasons why -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath didn't get called?

Tags: objective-c

I got a really strange problem.

My tableView has all the delegate and datasource set up.

Everything is fine.

However, clicking the rows do not activate:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I used custom cells.

After I click and click and click and click and click, sometimes it goes through.

I wonder what can possibly cause that? It's as if the customCell is "absorbing" the touch event or something or what?

Could that be why? If so, if we want to implement customCell and we want the tableView to handle the touch up event, what should we do?

Additional symptom:

If I remove user interaction enabled from the custom cell then the problem is solved with a catch.

[image]

However, clicking the button will somehow erase all the label texts in the customCell.

[image]

The implementation of the custom Cell is the following:

```
- (BGUIBusinessCellForDisplay *) initWithBiz: (Business *) biz
{
    if (self.biz == nil) //First time set up
    {
        self = [super init]; //If use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier then I shouldn't change the address self points to right
        NSString * className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
        //PO (className);
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil];
        self.frame =self.view.frame;
        [self addSubview:self.view]; //What is this for? self.view is of type BGCRBusinessForDisplay2. That view should be self, not one of it's subview Things don't work without it though
    }
    if (biz==nil)
    {
        return self;
    }

    _biz = biz;

    self.prominentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Isi: %@", biz.isiString];
    self.Title.text = biz.Title; //Let's set this one thing first
    self.Address.text=biz.ShortenedAddress;

    //if([self.distance isNotEmpty]){
    self.DistanceLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dm",[biz.Distance intValue]];
    self.PinNumber.text =biz.StringPinLineAndNumber;
    NSString * URLString=nil;
    if(biz.Images.allObjects.count!=0){
        //self.boolImage=[NSNumber numberWithBool:true];
        Image * image=(biz.Images.allObjects)[0];
        URLString = image.URL;
        URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://54.251.34.144/thumbnailer/Thumbnailer.ashx?imageURL=%@",URLString.UTF8Encode];
        //url=[NSURL URLWithString:image.URL];
    }else{
        float latitude = biz.getCllLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        float longitude = biz.getCllLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&zoom=16&size=160x160&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true&center=%f,%f&markers=size:small|color:blue|%f,%f",latitude,longitude,latitude,longitude];
        URLString = URLString.UTF8Encode;

    }


    //Should add code and add loading indicator here
    [BGHPTools doBackground:^{
        UIImage * imageBiz = [BGMDImageCacherAndDownloader getImageFromURL:URLString];

        [BGHPTools doForeGround:^{
            self.Image.image=imageBiz;
            [self.Image makeRound];
        }];
    }];

    //self.view=self.view;

    /*if (self.tableViewCell == Nil)//Instantiate that tableviewCell
    {
        PO(self.tableViewCell);
    }
    self.tableViewCell.business = bis;
    self.pinLbl.text = bis.StringPinLineAndNumber;
    self.lblTitle.text=bis.Title;
    //self.pinLbl.text=bis.pinNumber;*/
    //}
    /*self.name=[dict objectForKey:@"Title"];
     self.address=[dict objectForKey:@"Street"];
     CLLocation * cll=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[[dict objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[[dict objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue]];
     self.distance=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[cll distanceFromLocation:[cachedProperties currentLocation]]];*/

    return self;
```

Update: I already figure out why the texts are gone. Turns out my background is white. When a row got selected, the text suddenly turn into white. So by setting selected style to blue I sort of get that "fixed".

However, I still do not see where in my code I specify that all label texts should be white if the underlying tableViewCell is selected.

After all, what's selected is the cell, not the label. How the hell the label knows that it has to turn white is beyond me.

Comment: Where are you defining your custom table view cell?

Comment: Can you share your custom class implementation?

Comment: Are you 100% sure this method is spelled correctly in your code? What you posted is correct but is your real code the same? Are you 100% sure the table view's delegate is setup correctly. Seeing data just means the data source is correct. But this is a delegate method.

Comment: Don't refer to self.biz in your init routine. That translates to calling [self biz] before you're initialized.

Comment: Upvote back up to 0 for meaningful/detailed edits.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. It has something to do with my way of implementing custom cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to update that I think I have figured out what the problem is but still can't solve that quite right yet. And well the update is comprehensive so I think it should be an answer though I hope it's not the answer because some puzzle is still missing.

All the problem is interrelated.

The problem is in this line:

```
[self addSubview:self.view];
```

I basically turn that into:

Basically the my custom view cell has a view whose type is also tableViewCell. That view cover the real tableViewCell.

That's why when user interaction is enabled, that view will absorb the user's interaction.

That's also why the label "disappear". What happen is the label doesn't disappear. The label got highlighted and become white. However, what's highlighted is the tableViewCell not the opague view. The white opague self.view is still white while the tableCell itself is tinted with blue. So the label becomes white in the middle of white background and is gone.

I think I should replace [self addSubview:self.view] into self= self.view

However, that would mean changing the value of self. Yes it's in init. But it's still awkward. If anyone has the WAY to implement custom subclass of UI with XIB it'll be great because I haven't found one till now.

Awkward.

I wonder if we can draw a pointer to an XIB and specify that the outlet is self itself.

If that fail, I'll set background of self to white and background of self.view to transparent.

After tons of error and trying I did this:

self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.frame =self.view.frame;

```
/*PO(self.view.subviews);
PO(self.subviews);
PO(self.Title.superview);
PO(self.Title);
PO(self.view);
PO(self.Title.superview);
PO(self.view.contentView);*/
//Suck all the subviews from my minions
for (UIView* aSubView in self.view.contentView.subviews) {
    [self.contentView addSubview: aSubView];
    //[self.contentView add]
}
```

Basically I "move" all the subViews of my view object to my self object. There is a catch though that when subclassing tableViewCell I should move the subviews of the contentView. Who knows why.

At the end I just set self.view to nil for it's no longer needed and my program works as expected.

Also to set background of your tableViewCell, you need also to set the background of self.contentView rather than self.view.

Another approach you can try is to use story board. Alternatively you can just move the contentView of the self.view to self.

Comment: You instantiate the table cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, so instead of getting a generic tableviewcell and then replacing it, do your loabNib in that routine.

Comment: True, but rather ugly.  It would be much better to load your nib directly as the cell you return.  See the code I added to my answer above (to get the code formatting).

Comment: Your answer is good. But the issue is there is not outlet in nib called self. There is only an outlet called self.view. So how to deal with that? My way to do it is to move all subViews of the self.view to self. Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely thing is that a view in your custom cell is absorbing the touch.  Sometimes this is what you want, e.g. a button that does something, rather than selecting the entire cell.  Assuming you don't want this, then just set those views' userInteractionEnabled property to NO.

--Additional code for custom NIB loading.

All you have to do is register the NIB in your viewDidLoad routine:

```
[tableView registerNib: [UINib nibWithNibName:@"yourCellNibName" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"yourCellTypeID"]
```

and then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath just call:

```
newCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier @"yourCellTypeID"];
...
return newCell;
```

And it will load a cell from your XIB (or give you one from the previously used queue).

Comment: In my previous code the whole tableViewCell is absorbing touch and doing just fine. I'll check.

Comment: Removing userInteractionEnabled from the tableViewCell help solve the problem. Not sure how.

Comment: Hmm.... this could be a better way. I already vote up. The thing is I want to set the stuff on a different file rather than cellForRowAtIndexPath. In fact, I do not want tableViewController to know too much. Also even if load the nib, there is no outlet called "self". There is only an outlet called self.view.

Comment: Well, the only thing your TVC needs to know is the name of the nib file. Everything else (that's not already in the xib file) could be in your custom cell's initWithBiz routine, (which would still be referring to self). Note all that moving frames and views stuff isn't necessary now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Storyboard to handle the interface, instead of using:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Try using

```
#pragma mark --- Push selectedObject to the detailView ---

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    RRAppDelegate *myAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"PushObjectSegue"]) {
        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RRObjectViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.selectedObject = [myAppDelegate.goals  objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
    }
}
```

I was having the same problem with the method you used and instead used this, it started working perfectly. Of course you'd have to adapt the code to your app's viewControllers and data source because I used my AppDelegate as the datasource, and I wasn't using a custom cell.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you'r implementing that method and not

```
deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated
```