# selectionStyle in iPhone UITableViewCell selectionStyle when editing?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable the UITableView selection highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting)

When you tap a row in a `UITableView`, the row is highlighted and selected. Is it possible to disable this so tapping a row does nothing?

Comment: In the dup article, I prefer the lower-vote answer that sets the allowsSelection=NO on property on the tableView.

Comment: Setting `allowsSelection` to `NO` is good, but only if you want the entire table view to have unselectable rows. For more fine-grain control over individual cells' selectability, use `UITableViewCell`'s `selectionStyle` property instead.

Comment: In 2020, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64582629/171933

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes below code will disable user interaction , if you jut want to disable some certain cells you need to write some if - else methods

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This will prevent cells from receiving touch events, and that is probably not what he wants.

Comment: well if you disable user interaction user can not tap it:), and he uses probably a fake account anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you have buttons or anything on your cell that still needs to be 'touchable', than just set the selection style to none:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

If it just a cell with text than you can do like Space Dust suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting).

Grab the `UITableViewCell` instance and set the following property:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //do ur stuff

}
```