# How can I stop the clicking on a ViewCell from changing the background color for a brief time?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML code:

```
<TableView x:Name="tableView" Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="True">
   <TableSection>
      <TableSection.Title>
         Card Selection
      </TableSection.Title>
      <ViewCell Height="50">
         <Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="deselectGridLink" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
               <Label TextColor="Blue" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" x:Name="deselectLink" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Deselect All" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="deselectGridLabel" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
               <Label TextColor="Silver" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" x:Name="deselectLabel" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Deselect All" />
            </Grid>
         </Grid>
       </ViewCell>
       <ViewCell Height="50">
          <Grid x:Name="selectGridLink" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
             <Label TextColor="Blue" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" x:Name="selectLink" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Select All" />
           </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
   </TableSection>
</TableView>
```

When other parts of my code call: `SetPageDetails()` then the label in the grid is changed to a link or the link is changed to a label. So for this when it is a label I would like to have no background flash event and no action called.

I attach a tap gesture recognizer like this. Note it's all on one line but covers two lines so it's more visible here in the SO question:

```
deselectGridLink.GestureRecognizers
      .Add(NewTapGestureForUpdateCategories(false));

    private TapGestureRecognizer NewTapGestureForUpdateCategories(bool val)
    {
        return new TapGestureRecognizer()
        {
            Command = new Command(() =>
            {
                App.DB.UpdateAllCategoryGroups(val);
                App.DB.UpdateAllCategories(val);
                GetPageData();
                RemoveTableViewClickSection();
                tableView.Root.Add(CreateTableSection());
            })
        };
    }
```

When the user clicks the row when deselectGridLink grid is visible then:

- The deselectGridLink visibility is set to false
- The deselectGridLabel visibility is set to true

  ```
  private void SetPageDetails()
  {
      Title = App.cardCountForSelectedCategories + (App.cardCountForSelectedCategories == 1 ? " Card Selected" : " Cards Selected");
      if (App.cardCountForSelectedCategories == 0)
      {
          deselectGridLink.IsVisible = false;
          deselectGridLabel.IsVisible = true;
      }
      else
      {
          deselectGridLink.IsVisible = true;
          deselectGridLabel.IsVisible = false;
      }
  }
  ```

The effect of this is that the grid link text will change to silver and the link becomes a label.

However even though it's a gray color label when the label is clicked there is still a brief background row color change from white to a dark color when the label is clicked. I assume it's just the way a view cell works.

Is there a way to suppress this from happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***EDIT 1*** - Updated answer as per updates to question. i.e. add support for switching between highlight enabled/disabled mode.

***EDIT 2*** - Restructure answer and add more details.

## Option-1: Enable/disable view-cell through `IsEnabled`

The simplest option would be to use the [IsEnabled](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.IsEnabled/) property, which in turn enables/disables the background flash behavior. The only downside to this approach is that it will also disable the taps on child controls, i.e. tap events/gesture recognizer(s) will not be triggered if parent view-cell's `IsEnabled` is `false`.

**For example:**

*XAML*

```
<!-- Add name attribute to view-cell -->
<ViewCell x:Name="deselectCell" ..>
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="deselectGridLink" ..
    ....
</ViewCell>
```

*Code-behind*

```
private void SetPageDetails()
{
    if (App.cardCountForSelectedCategories == 0)
    {
        deselectCell.IsEnabled = false; //disable background flash
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        deselectCell.IsEnabled = true;
        ...
    }
}
```

**Recommendation 1 - Use data-binding and triggers**

Instead of controlling visibility for each label in code-behind, you can use triggers and data-binding as follows (view-model will have a `IsDeselectEnabled` property):

```
<ViewCell IsEnabled="{Binding IsDeselectEnabled}" Height="50">
    <Label Margin="20,0,20,0" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Deselect All">
        <Label.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsDeselectEnabled}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Blue" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsDeselectEnabled}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Silver" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
</ViewCell>
```

**Recommendation 2 - Use triggers with view as source**

```
<ViewCell x:Name="deselectCell" Height="50">
    <Label Margin="20,0,20,0" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Deselect All">
        <Label.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, Source={x:Reference deselectCell}}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Blue" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, Source={x:Reference deselectCell}}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Silver" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
</ViewCell>
```

---

## Option-2: Enable/disable highlight, but allow taps

To allow taps while toggling `ViewCell`'s background-highlight behavior, we will need to implement platform-renderer(s).

In case of iOS, we can use [SelectionStyle](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewCellSelectionStyle/) to toggle this behavior, while in case of android, we can use [Clickable](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Views.View.Clickable/) property.

**Shared control:**

```
public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty AllowHighlightProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "AllowHighlight", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomViewCell),
            defaultValue: true);

    public bool AllowHighlight
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowHighlightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AllowHighlightProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**iOS renderer:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomViewCell), typeof(CustomViewCellRenderer))]
namespace SampleApp.iOS
{
    public class CustomViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        UITableViewCell _nativeCell;

        //get access to the associated forms-element and subscribe to property-changed
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            _nativeCell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

            var formsCell = item as CustomViewCell;

            if (formsCell != null)
            {
                formsCell.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
                formsCell.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
            }

            //and, update the style 
            SetStyle(formsCell);

            return _nativeCell;
        }

        void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var formsCell = sender as CustomViewCell;
            if (formsCell == null)
                return;
            //TODO: Trying to find a nicer and more robust way to dispose and unsubscribe :(
            if (_nativeCell == null)
                formsCell.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;

            if (e.PropertyName == CustomViewCell.AllowHighlightProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                SetStyle(formsCell);
            }
        }

        private void SetStyle(CustomViewCell formsCell)
        {
            //added this code as sometimes on tap, the separator disappears, if style is updated before tap animation finishes 
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613117/how-do-you-prevent-uitableviewcellselectionstylenone-from-removing-cell-separato
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50), () => {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    if (formsCell.AllowHighlight)
                        _nativeCell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default;
                    else
                        _nativeCell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
                });
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Android renderer:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomViewCell), typeof(CustomViewCellRenderer))]
namespace SampleApp.Droid
{
    public class CustomViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        Android.Views.View _nativeCell;

        protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, Android.Content.Context context)
        {
            _nativeCell = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);

            SetStyle();

            return _nativeCell;
        }

        // this one is simpler as the base class has a nice override-able method for our purpose - so we don't need to subscribe 
        protected override void OnCellPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCellPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if(e.PropertyName == CustomViewCell.AllowHighlightProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                SetStyle();
            }
        }

        private void SetStyle()
        {
            var formsCell = Cell as CustomViewCell;
            if (formsCell == null)
                return;

            _nativeCell.Clickable = !formsCell.AllowHighlight;
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample usage 1 - Through data-binding**

```
<local:CustomViewCell  AllowHighlight="{Binding IsHighlightEnabled}" ..>
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="deselectGridLink" ..
    ...
</local:CustomViewCell>
```

**Sample usage 2 - Through code-behind**

*XAML*

```
<!-- Add name attribute to view-cell -->
<local:CustomViewCell x:Name="deselectCell" ..>
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="deselectGridLink" ..
    ...
</local:CustomViewCell>
```

*Code-behind*

```
private void SetPageDetails()
{
    if (App.cardCountForSelectedCategories == 0)
    {
        deselectCell.AllowHighlight= false; //disable background flash
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        deselectCell.AllowHighlight= true;
        ...
    }
}
```

---

## Option-3: Disable highlight, selection for all items

This particularly applies to `ListView`. *The updated question now specifies that the cells are part of `TableView`, so this option is no longer valid in current question context*.

You will need to implement platform renderers to disable highlight colors, and add `ItemTapped` handler to `ListView` to disable selection by setting `SelectedItem` as null always. References used:

1. [Disable highlight item](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/152977/#Comment_152977)
2. [Disable selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26682064/7292772)

### Code

To get started, create a custom view-cell:

```
public class NoSelectViewCell : ViewCell { }
```

Implement iOS renderer as:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NoSelectViewCell), typeof(NoSelectViewCellRenderer))]
namespace SampleApp.iOS
{
    public class NoSelectViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            var nativeCell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            nativeCell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            return nativeCell;
        }
    }
}
```

Implement android renderer as:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NoSelectViewCell), typeof(NoSelectViewCellRenderer))]
namespace SampleApp.Droid
{
    public class NoSelectViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, Android.Content.Context context)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);

            cell.Focusable = false;
            cell.FocusableInTouchMode = false;

            var listView = parent as Android.Widget.ListView;
            if (listView != null)
            {
                listView.SetSelector(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
                listView.CacheColorHint = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent.ToAndroid();
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

### Sample Usage:

**XAML**

```
<ListView ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:NoSelectViewCell Height="50">
               <Grid>
                  <Grid x:Name="deselectGridLink" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
                     <Label TextColor="Blue" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" x:Name="deselectLink" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Deselect All" />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid x:Name="deselectGridLabel" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
                     <Label TextColor="Silver" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" x:Name="deselectLabel" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Deselect All" />
                  </Grid>
               </Grid>
            </local:NoSelectViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Code-behind**

```
void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    // don't do anything if we just de-selected the row
    if (e.Item == null) return;
    // do something with e.SelectedItem
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
}
```

Comment: Hi @G. Sharada - I am sorry I think my question was not clear enough.  What I am looking for is just to be able to disable the background click effect if the view cell contents are for a label and not a link.  With the code I switch it from being a label to a link dynamically so that once the user has clicked to remove all rows then the deselect then becomes a link. Can you have a look at the revised question and let me know if you think your solution could be adapted.  In other words I think I need some way of specifying if that ViewCell has or does not have the background click.

Comment: @Alan2 : I think I understand it better now. I will the update the answer and let you know.

Comment: Hi @Alan2 : I have updated the answer as per my understanding. It has three options to choose from - the first one allows you to toggle highlight behavior from code-behind/view model while allowing taps, while the second option basically disables the row. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I will check these out today and accept your answer or add something to the comments.

Comment: Hi @Alan2 - Just an FYI.. I have updated the answer in terms of structure and explanation. I am also planning to update iOS renderer code a little bit for more robust dispose logic. I will update you once I am able to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I will wait a while then. Looking forward to seeing the changes.

Comment: Hi @Alan2 : from my analysis it looks like unless [`ViewTableCell`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Cells/ViewCellRenderer.cs#L48) is made public - we can't simplify the dispose/cleanup logic we have in the iOS renderer. If you are ok with using a `TextCell` instead of `ViewCell` - then I would recommend using property-change logic in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45784618/7292772).

Comment: Hi, You mention it cannot be simplified.  Do you think it's okay to leave it as you have coded then or do you think there will be a problem if I implement what you coded?  I would really like to continue using ViewCells as we want to keep everything as much the same as possible.

Comment: Hi @Alan2 : Yes, we can use the code as it is - I was hoping to avoid subscribing to `PropertyChanged` event as `ViewTableCell` is already doing that.  - but as the type is inaccessible - we can't reuse the logic in there

Comment: Thanks,  I'll mark the answer as accepted.  If I have more questions related to this I will create another question and reference this question of yours.

Answer (score 1):

What G.Sharada proposes is very nicely working for iOS, but on Android I still had blinks on click.
Adding this line to the styles file solved the problem.

```
<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
```