# UITableView cell's seperators disappear when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, separator

When I select a UITableViewCell and start scrolling to the point where the cells disappear from the screen, the seperators on those cells disappear once they reappear on the screen.

Delegate:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell == nil){
        if(Type == Scene){
            Group *scene = [[appdata getScenes]objectAtIndex:lastRequestedPropertyPosition];
            [selectedArray addObject:scene.id];
        }else if(Type == Product){
            Device *device = [[appdata getDevices]objectAtIndex:lastRequestedPropertyPosition];
            [selectedArray addObject:device.id];
        }
    }else{
        [selectedArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:cell.tag]];
    }
}
```

Datasource:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"protoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"protoCell"];
    }
    Group *group = [[appdata getScenes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(group != nil){
        [cell.textLabel setText:group.name];
    }

    cell.tag = group.id.intValue;
    return cell;
}
```

Can anyone tell what went wrong here?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Using this just makes the separator disappear on select instead of just keeping the separator there.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell == nil){
        if(Type == Scene){
            Group *scene = [[appdata getScenes]objectAtIndex:lastRequestedPropertyPosition];
            [selectedArray addObject:scene.id];
        }else if(Type == Product){
            Device *device = [[appdata getDevices]objectAtIndex:lastRequestedPropertyPosition];
            [selectedArray addObject:device.id];
        }
    }else{
        [selectedArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:cell.tag]];
    }
}
```

Comment: this link may help u 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212476/uitableview-separator-line-disappears-when-selecting-cells-in-ios7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of my issue was the fact I used a blue color shade to show a cell being selected. This shade however was a little too big. It was covering the seperator

Answer (score 0):

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, if you send both messages below, the issue is visually resolved (with the probable performance cost).

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

For this to work (for me), `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` must contain `animated:YES`. The animation used for `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` doesn't matter.