# uitableviewcell corruption (saw from the bottom) on selection

Tags: ios, uitableview

I get this mini-horror sawtooth artifact at the bottom
of the cell on UITableViewCell selection

[image]

[image]

is there any cure?
ios version agnostic, happens on 9 and 10
both real devices and simulator

UPD: using first answer here: [UITableView separator line disappears when selecting cells in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212476/uitableview-separator-line-disappears-when-selecting-cells-in-ios7)
switching from blue selection style to style none masks this issue,
not sure if feedbackless cell selection style would be acceptable
for my employer though.

Comment: Which UI component have you used to display text?

Comment: vanilla UILabel

Comment: Is this happened with other colors and fonts?

Comment: having switched from system font to footnote (accessibility) over blue background I no longer see the saw. I'm switching to autoheight given the hints received so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal sufficient change to kill the artifact was to change
the default background for the label from default to white
to match the cell background.

In any event killing transparency fixed this, whatever that was.
A bug in GPU or GLES driver or higher up the stack. Whatever.

UPD20171024: closeViewAndMoveMapToPlase: is the culprit in another table.

This looks like a single symptom multiple causes issue.

Answer (score 1):

- First check is height for your cell is correct or not.
- If using autolayout and height is correct then verify the constraint for this label with proper hugging priority and compression resistance.
- If using autolayout, also make sure you have set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for your label
- Also call `layoutIfNeeded` for your cell `[cell layoutIfNeeded]`

Comment: I did find autolayout issues through your answer but that does not resolve the artifact.

Comment: also try to use `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` delgate if not used