# how to highlight image in cell of a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView and each cell contains an image. Now I want to highlight the image to become highlighted like the iPhone app icon when you select it.

I had try this code but it doesn't work,it just highlighted the background.

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {  Cell* cell = (Cell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.img.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5 ];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: instead of shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath use didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I hope it will help you   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to use didSelect and didDeselect delegates. When the user selects the cell, grab the imageview in collectionView cell and change any property as you wish.

Example code.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UICollectionViewCell *selectedCell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[selectedCell viewWithTag:101];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever-image-you-want"]];

}
```

If the user selects another cell, in other words deSelects the previous cell you can change the cell using. didDeselectItemAtIndexPath delegate

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UICollectionViewCell *deSelectedCell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[deSelectedCell viewWithTag:101];
imageView.image = nil;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a reloadItemsAtIndexPaths: there instead, then in cellForItemAtIndexPath, check if [[collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] containsObject: indexPath] If true, then just change the cell's attributes there.

I hope it will help you. Thanks.