# Table View Cell Stays Highlighted No Matter What

Tags: swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

My storyboard-based `UITableViewController` subclass pushes another view controller into the navigation when the user taps one of the table view cells.

I am using a ***segue*** to accomplish this, and **not** doing it programmatically with `pushViewController(:animated:)`.

**The problem** I'm having is that my table view cell stays highlighted (light gray) all along, even after popping the view controller (again, with an 'unwind' segue). The only way to clear it is to call `tableView.reloadData()`.

---

I have tried:

1. Setting:

   ```
   self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = true
   ```

   in `viewDidLoad()` (Should not be necessary, since it's already the    default: The template code has `self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear =     false` commented out, and suggests to uncomment it to override the default functionality).
2. Also:

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)

       if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
           tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
       }
   }
   ```

   ...to no avail.

   **EDIT:** Turns out `viewDidAppear()` is **not** called on navigation pop, only after being added to the view hierarchy (e.g., `addSubview()`). Placing this code in `viewWillAppear()` **does** the trick. But my question at the end of this post still stands.
3. I have also tried implementing this method:

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
   }
   ```

   ...but it is not being called (perhaps because of the segue?)

The only thing that successfully unhighlights the cell is calling:

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

...from within `prepareForSegue()`. But that happens on *push*, and I want to de-highlight my cell on *pop*.

Do I need to setup a dedicated unwind method for the push (cell tap) segue, and unhighlight there?

**Why doesn't it work out-of-the-box**, even though I am subclassing `UITableViewController`?

Comment: You want to deSelect cell when you pop from that destinationViewController, right?

Comment: Yes. But it isn't happening, even though I explicitly set `self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = true`.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39868238/3411787

Comment: @ZaidPathan I think OP want to show the selected cell.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Have you try to deSelect cell in viewWillAppear?

Comment: @NiravD The given link is to stop Highlighting cell on selection and not for show the selected cell.

Comment: @ZaidPathan OP want to show the deSelect animation on the pop of destination Controller read question perfectly.

Comment: @NiravD , May be you're right I've answered from Title of the question.

Comment: @NiravD Yes, and that works (see edit to my question). But I was expecting  `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` to work (a **am** calling `super`).

Comment: @NicolasMiari Try to implement `viewWillAppear`, `func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {     super.viewWillAppear(animated)     }`

Comment: That's what I did, and it works. But I still don't understand **why** I need to do this, and `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear ` does not kick in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like what you mention, using `tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)`

However, instead of having it in:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

You should be putting it in:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // You other cell selected functions here ...
    // then add the below at the end of it.
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

`didDeselectRowAt` will not be called until a row is deselected. So in order to de-select the cell, you should be adding it in the `didSelectRow`. This way whenever a cell is selected and `didSelectRow` get trigger, you will run your other code and also `de-select` the cell at the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

The third option should work, I think you just accidentally autocompleted with didDeselectRow, not didSelectRow.