# Swift - Image color resets when Alert is displayed

Tags: swift, uiimage, urlsession

So in my iOS app I have a menu designed like this:

[image]

The Images are created with the following code:

```
cell.imageCell?.image = menuItems[indexPath.row].image
    cell.imageCell.image = cell.imageCell.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    cell.imageCell.tintColor = MenuTableViewController.fontColor
    cell.imageCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

This code is placed in the tableview cellForRowAt function. Now all the different viewcontrollers(HomeViewController, InfoViewController etc...) have no access at all to the menu controller and thus are not able to change the color of the image and nowhere else am I changing the color of these images. Now when I press one of the tabs that don't use any Alerts or modal views like home or info, the images stay perfectly fine, however when I press on Weather or excursions which download a json file with URLSession  dataTask and display an alert telling to please wait, the images turn grey like the following:

[image]

I'm not sure how this is even possible that one viewcontroller can change another viewcontrollers subviews.
Thanks in advance
-Jorge

Comment: Perhaps what you see is a dimmed presentation of your icons. Don't use image templates or set `tintAdjustmentMode` to `normal` to stop fading icons. Usually that happens if you display alert or modal controller.

Comment: You are right it wasn't the URLSessions problem, it was the alert telling to please wait that changed the color, and setting the `tintAdjustmentMode` to `normal` did the trick. If you want to post an answer i'll accept it as the right one.

Comment: glad I guessed it right. I have posted an answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps what you see is a dimmed presentation of your icons. Don't use image templates or set `tintAdjustmentMode` to `normal` to stop fading icons. Usually that happens if you display alert or modal controller.

Comment: Thank you for this. It fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its the default UITableViewCell click style.
Try to set the style to **none**,
as answered here: [How can I disable the UITableView selection highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting)

Swift:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
```

Comment: If you feel that this question is a duplicate, flag it as such.  It's generally a bad practice to duplicate answers.

Comment: @JAL its not a duplicate, he described a certain problem, and i suggested a solution. the link above just shows how to do it.