# Cell selection color in UITableView iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios10

I have this problem with tableView: despite I set all background fields with darkText color when I select a cell the background changes to the light one as you can see in the attached.
How I could solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to change the color, or turn off the selection color?

Comment: Turn off the selection color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable the UITableView selection highlighting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting)

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/191245/790842

Comment: I would a blank selection color not disabling selection

Answer (score 1):

add `cell.selectionStyle = .none` in cellForRowAtIndex. This will remove the selectionColor from that cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    // do your cell customisation here..

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below method to disable cell selection when user interacts.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

 //Method 1: Simply disable the user cell interaction.
  cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
 //or
 //Method 2: use UITableViewCellSelectionStyle to none
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

return cell
}
```